# Cursor-based pagination with Jetpack Compose LazyColumn?

Tags: android, pagination, android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement `LazyColumn` with cursor-based pagination.
My api model looks like:

```
data class TransfersListResponse(
    val paging: PagingDto,
    val items: List<TransactionDataDto>
)

data class PagingDto(
    val next: String?,
    val prev: String?,
)
```

Both `next` and `prev` can be null if there is no elements after or before.

1. I load first page only with `take` parameter and I'll receive list of transactions with `prev = null, next = someId`
2. After this I need to load second page with `take` and `after = someId1` and I'll receive list with `prev` and `next` ids
3. When I'll scroll to the bottom I need just to load new items with `after`, that will be equals with `next` from current page
4. But, when I'll return to the top of the `LazyColumn` I need to **reload** my fist page to check `prev` parameter for it.

- If `prev` is still `null` - then there's no need to do anything
- If `prev` now `is not null` - I need to load new items with `before` perameter

**NOTE:** `id` of elements in the list `!= id` from `paging` object

I use MVI approach, actually I understand this logic but I have troubles with implementation

Comment: what is cursor based pagination?

Comment: https://jsonapi.org/profiles/ethanresnick/cursor-pagination/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if that is the right approach but you can may be use `item{}` blocks in combination with `LaunchedEffect()`

```
@Composable
fun myList(){
    LazyColumn {
        item {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                // do something when the first item is shown on the screen
                //you are at the top of the LazyColumn
                //i.e. load previous depending on your logic
            }
        }
        items(100) {
            // ... your normal Lazy column items and composables here
        }
        item {
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                // do something when the last item is shown on the screen
                //you are at the bottom of the LazyColumn
                //i.e. load next depending on your logic

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not the answer on my question. I asked about cursor-based paging